# No search results for a # that really exists

Tags: r, rtweet

I am analysing #angtunaynalalake or #AngTunayNaLalake - a tweet that is famous in the Philippines. I run the following code but there are 0 results. I tried the same code using other famous #s like #MeToo or as #rstats and the code was successful. I tried using 'lalake' instead of '#angtunaynalalake' and again the code was successful.

I was able to get results for #angtunaynalalake when I use twitteR. I want to use rtweet because it can give more search results than twitteR.

Why do you think this happens?

```
create_token(
  app = "my_twitter_research_app",
  consumer_key = "xxxx",
  consumer_secret = "xxxx",
  access_token = "xxxx",
  access_secret = "xxxx")


> rt <- search_tweets(
+   "#angtunaynalalake", n = 25000, retryonratelimit = TRUE
+ )
```

Searching for tweets...
This may take a few seconds...
Finished collecting tweets!

```
> rt
```

data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with the twitter API and not with the rtweet package.

See this quote from the [twitter API page.](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html)

> "Keep in mind that the search index has a 7-day limit. In other words, no tweets will be found for a date older than one week."

The most recent tweet to #angtunaynalalake seems to have been in January 2019, therefore the standard twitter API won't find any tweets.

If you need to access tweets older than 7-days, consider the [twitter API pricing plans.](https://developer.twitter.com/en/pricing.html)